# ReactJS - Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting this weird error in my React that says

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ContactTemplate`.
```

I tried to remove each of the import to see where the error is, but nothing works.

My ContactTemplate.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from '~/components/interface/Container';
import PreviewBar from '~/components/PreviewBar';
import HeroFull from '~/components/HeroFull/HeroFull';
import { Wrapper, Columns, Paragraph, BigText } from './ContactTemplate.styles';
import { Link } from '~/components/interface/Link';

const ContactTemplate = ({ preview }) => {
  const data = [
    {
      name: 'Name 1',
      job: 'Bestuursrechts',
      phone: '+31 (0) 612345678',
      email: 'Email',
      link: 'https://www.linkedin.com',
    },
    {
      name: 'Name 2',
      job: 'Intellectuele eigendom en contractenrecht',
      phone: '+31 (0) 612345678',
      email: 'email',
      link: 'https://www.linkedin.com',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        {preview && <PreviewBar />}
        <HeroFull
          title="Contact"
          intro="We offer ...."
        />
      </Wrapper>
      <Container>
        <Columns>
          {data.map(item => (
            <div>
              <BigText>{item.name}</BigText>
              <Paragraph>{item.job}</Paragraph>
              <Paragraph>{item.phone}</Paragraph>
              <Paragraph>{item.email}</Paragraph>
              <Link>{item.link}</Link>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Columns>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default ContactTemplate;
```

Could someone help me out with this please?
If there are more files needed I'll add them on request.

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Probably you are trying to do a named import(`import {Component}`) for a default export or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're trying to `import { ContactTemplate } from "./ContactTemplate"`, but you're using `export default`. At this point you should `import ContactTemplate from "./ContactTemplate"`

Can you confirm if this is the case?
Can you show the component, where you import and trying to use `ContactTemplate`?

Comment: I already have ```import ContactTemplate from '~/templates/Contact/ContactTemplate';```

Comment: I'd suggest two things. First off, try console logging the preview prop inside the function to make sure it's not undefined, and second thing is making sure that the components that you already imported are not problematic in any possible way, whether they're imported from the right file, or whether they're returning undefined values from inside their files

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. The first problem was that my Docker was stuck so I had to restart it. After I restarted it I tried to remove each import individually to see where the problem was and it was the `{ Link }` that needed to be just `Link`. Thanks everyone else for helping!